# Electron - How to keep consistent contents size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

There is a problem with the window contents. In the index.html file, everything appears correctly in terms of size. However, when clicking on the "Click here" link to navigate to register.html, the contents enlarge. The issue persists even without CSS, and the useContentSize:true setting is enabled in the main.js file.

Here's the gif of both pages so you can spot the difference easily.
[image]

Exact same resolution, css disabled, both pages are set with useContentSize:true and both are using this exact same settings in main.js

```js
useContentSize:true,
width: 700,
height: 700,
minWidth: 700,
minHeight: 700,
frame: false,
```

So how would I be able to resolve this issue?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>stuff</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/styles.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/appFunctions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainApp">
      <div class="topBar">
        <div class="titleBar">
          <img class="topimgicon" src="src/icons/Icon.png" alt="" />
          <div class="title">home</div>
        </div>
        <div class="titleBarBtns">
          <button id="minimizeBtn" class="topBtn minimizeBtn" title="Minimize"></button>
          <button id="maxResBtn" class="topBtn maximizeBtn" title="Maximize"></button>
          <button id="closeBtn" class="topBtn closeBtn" title="Close"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contentArea">     
        <div class="wrapper">
          <form class="loginForm" method="post">
            <!-- <div class="loginForm"></div> -->
            <div class="imgcontainer">
              <img src="../img/logo2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="field email">
                <div class="input-area">
                  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input" >
                  <span class="error-message"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field email">
                <div class="input-area">
                  <input  id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input" >      
                </div>
              </div>
              <input class="button" id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="register_acct">
            <p>Don't have an account yet?</p>
            <a href="src/directories/register.html">Click here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

register.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css" />
    <script src="../js/appFunctions.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/register.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainApp">
      <div class="topBar">
        <div class="titleBar">
          <img class="topimgicon" src="../icons/Icon.png" alt="" />
          <div class="title"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="titleBarBtns">
        <button id="minimizeBtn" class="topBtn minimizeBtn" title="Minimize"></button>
        <button id="maxResBtn" class="topBtn maximizeBtn" title="Maximize"></button>
        <button id="closeBtn" class="topBtn closeBtn" title="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentArea">     
      <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="loginForm" method="post">
          <!-- <div class="loginForm"></div> -->
          <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img src="../img/logo2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="field email">
              <label> Create your new account</label>
              <div class="field email">
                <div class="input-area">
                  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Create Username" class="registerf">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field email">
                <div class="input-area">
                  <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="registerf">      
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-area">
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="registerf">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field email">
              <div class="input-area">
                <input id="site" type="text" placeholder="Site Code" class="registerf"  maxlength="5">      
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="register_buttons_group">
            <input class="button" id="goBackBtn" type="button" value="Go Back">
            <input class="button" id="register" type="submit" value="Register">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

register function in main.js:

```js
function registerWindow() {
    winregister = new BrowserWindow({
        useContentSize:true,
        width: 700,
        height: 700,
        minWidth: 700,
        minHeight: 700,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            devTools: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js/register.js')
        }
    });

    winregister.loadFile('src/directories/register.html');
}
```

Version:

```json
"name": "login",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron ."
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
  "electron": "^19.1.9"
},
"dependencies": {
  "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
  "express": "^4.18.1",
  "express-openid-connect": "^2.8.0",
  "express-session": "^1.17.3",
  "gridstack": "^5.1.1",
  "gulp": "^4.0.2",
  "gulp-less": "^5.0.0",
  "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
  "jquery": "^3.6.0",
  "mysql": "^2.18.1",
  "update-electron-app": "^2.0.1",
  "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
},
```

Comment: How are the sizes of your HTML images set out are they not?  And what type of images are used? Electron uses Chrome as its embedded browser so any specific fix will be tailored to it.  You should add the HTML code of both pages to your question for a speedy answer by the SO community.

Comment: @midnight-coding I disabled the css for testing, the image size and html are the same thing and I did not change anything. The img is PNG and I used both chrome and Firefox.. Still get the same issue. And I'll do that in a few for adding html codes.

Comment: What happens if you remove both the `useContentSize` and `frame` options from your window creation function in `main.js`? Does the size change between html files?

Comment: @midnight-coding The issues still persists after I remove both `useContentSize` and `frame`

Comment: I edited your question to adjust the code indentation whilst checking to see if any HTML tags were missing. In the `register.html` file you are missing the opening `<html>` tag and one of the closing `</div>` tags (either the `contentArea` class div tag or the `wrapper` class div tag. Add these missing tags to your HTML file and let me know if there is any change (positive, negative or none) to your original ‘contents size’ problem.

Comment: Oh wow,didn't realized I forgot to close the tags.. but when I closed it, the problem still persists but when I checked through the browsers (firefox and chrome) the size stayed consistent and did not changed... but through electron it still enlarge for some reason. @midnight-coding

Comment: OK, for everyones future reference, I have added the missing tags to your `register.html` file.

Comment: Next, I noticed that your icon `topimgicon` class within the `index.html` file uses `src/icons/Icon.png` as its path, but within the `register.html` file it uses `../icons/Icon.png` as its path. This leads me to believe that perhaps you are using a build system to maybe process your images in some way such as adjustment of width, height or DPI. Is this the case?

Comment: @midnight-coding Good question but no. I never touched anything regarding to the process of changing image/icon size

Comment: OK, let's completely eliminate the HTML render code side. Please remove all `<link>` and `<script>` tags from within the `<head>` tags of both files. If the result is the same then it is definitely an Electron issue and we can begin to concentrate on that. If the results normalise, then it is a HTML / JS / CSS issue after which we can then begin to concentrate on that. Let the know the results.

Comment: @midnight-coding Tried it and it still gives me the same error therefore it has to do with electron then...

Comment: What version of Electron are you running? Can you add to your question the full window creation function and (upon clicking the register link) the function where you change to `register.html`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I edited and added the function. And added the electron version as well.

Comment: have you tried overflow-y: hidden?

Comment: I know it looks like an Electron issue but I want you to do one more CSS check. Can you open Developer Tools (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`) for each page and go to the Network tab and reload the page (`Ctrl-R` for Windows). Check that `styles.css` and the same `styles.css` is loading in each page.

Comment: @Re9iNee I already have `overflow: hidden` but keep in mind I'm doing this without css loaded for testing purpose and it still gives the same issue.
@midnight-coding I just checked and each page has the same css loaded via the network tab

Comment: @Zyaan on the second picture there's a scroll bar, enable CSS for the sake of example and make overflow contents hidden.

Comment: This is turning out to be a tricky one. I wonder if the windows width, height, minWidth and minHeight all being set to 700px could be the cause of the issue? Try setting width and height of both windows to 800px whilst leaving the minWidth and minHeight at 700px. If all works well, try dragging the window(s) smaller in width and height and see if it glitches out then. Let me know the result.

Comment: @midnight-coding I changed the width and height to 800 and tested it out however the result is still the same. I also tried to resized the window by dragging, the size and location did not change, it stayed the same.  @ Re9iNee Completely understandable. I tried that and the result is still the same.

Comment: I am running out of idea's here. Apart from testing your whole project code base locally via a clone of a GitHub repository, all I can suggest now is to upgrade your version of Electron to the latest version. Currently you are running `19.1.9`. The latest version of Electron (at this moment in time) is `24.3.0`.

Comment: @midnight-coding all good, i'm going to try to update my electron now.

Comment: I just tried to update my electron but it still stuck at 19.1.9? I'll have to look into this further tomorrow.

Comment: Managed to successfully update the electron version to current 24.3 and the result are the same... I think I'll have to make entirely new electron app and try again? But before that I'm going to try to see if the result is the same as the previous file I had.

Comment: I solved the issue, apparently it was my laptop or the electron itself. I tried on my main PC and the issue disappeared.